# TYPO3 v10 404 error handling prduces duplicate content

Tags: error-handling, duplicates, typo3, http-status-code-404, typo3-10.x

I want to show the frontpage if a page ist not found (404). The sites > error handling to show content of another page is possible but the URL keeps the old/incorrect one. So the frontpage is appearing under two URLs and produces duplicate content.

How can I realize a real redirect to the frontpage or any other page?

Answer (score 1):

For this use-case, you have to write a custom page error handler.

Luckily, the redirect to a page is the example in the documentation: "[Example for a simple 404 ErrorHandler](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/ErrorHandling/WriteCustomErrorHandler.html#example-for-a-simple-404-errorhandler)"